# Thematic Legends in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

Does anyone know if it is possible to make a range label go over more than one line in MapInfo when doing thematic maps?

My legend has a limited width and I have not been able to find a way to get MapInfo to do this. The customize legend dialog doesn't seem to allow you to add text over two or more lines.

In the example below each item is wider than the frame on the layout that contains the legend. The frame is 7cm wide, and the legend items need 10cm when the text is on the same line.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem this is possible, I even tried putting something like "dasd" + Chr$(10) + "ad" in the workspace file and it just ignores it.  Could be a good feature request on: http://pbinsight.force.com/pbideas/ideaHome

Comment: I have submitted a feature request for legends that included this. There are quite a few things about legends in MapInfo that annoy me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be nothing you can do about this, other than make the amount of text you want on the legend item smaller (or make the font or swatch size smaller), or make your legend area wider! The text can not be on more than 1 line. I have submitted a feature request to get this changed with MapInfo.

Answer (score 4):

Not pretty but I have shortened the legend text and then added my own text (box) to the end and just group the graphics together.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Chr$(13).

Comment: Unfortunately this just adds the text Chr$(13) to the range label. Very annoying.

Comment: Sorry, it works with layers labels, but not with legend labels :(

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a "good" way to put the range labels in more than one line. If I had to do it, I would delete the range labels, then choose the swatch size "Large", and then add a text box on top (the large swatch size allows you to have room enough for two lines of text).

[image: example of MapInfo legend using two lines per title and ranges]

By the way, I often do have your same problem not with range labels but with the title of the legend. When I need to put the title of the legend in two lines I do it with the legend title and subtitle, by customizing the fonts and specifiying the same size and font, as in the picture.